# How to compare 2 groups (control + patient) to show significant differences?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, t-test, inference

I am conducting an experimental study. I have 2 groups: The first group contains 3 healthy persons and the other one contains 3 patients (sick people). For each person of the sudy, we collect several cells, from which we extract 3 features. The goal is to show significant differences between the 2 groups. In other way, we have:

[image]

x are numerical values

Which test is the more suitable to show significant difference between the patient and the healthy group?

I saw several tests like Hotelling, ANOVA..., but in those tests the mean of each group is computed on all cells of all the people of a group without making a difference between the person within the group. Is it possible to include person variablity in such test? Is 2-way ANOVA a solution to take into consideration the people in the comparison? The two independant variables (factors) are thus the identity of the person and its situation (Healthy or patient)?

Comment: A test is not enough in this case. A linear model is the natural progression, to include the variability of the patients you can include a random effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could include patient as a random effect in your model to account for correlation between cells from the same patient. Something like:

```r
lmer(group ~ feature1 + (1 | patient), data=data)
```

or

```r
aov(group ~ feature1 + Error(patient/feature1), data=data)
```

Syntax not tested, taken from [this blog](http://conjugateprior.org/2013/01/formulae-in-r-anova/).